# How to read csv file with emails and passwords and save results in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Maybe a simple one, but I cant get it to work by googling.
I have a csv file with Emails in Column A and Passwords in column b.
I want to save those in a dict {Email:Password}.

The code I have so far:

```
f = open('email_list_test.csv', 'r')

with f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in reader:
        print(row['Email'], row['Password'])
```

But it is not doing anything. Ideally I would just have a dict, that I can then iterate through later, as I want to pass those email password combinations on to a function.

My code now:

```
dict = {}

f = open('email_list_test.csv', 'r')

with f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        dict[row['Email']] = row['Password']
print(dict)
```

Sadly the dict is empty, even though I have a few test records in my csv.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "not doing anything"? What specifically happens when you run it?

Comment: The purpose of `with` is to *contain* the `open()` call. Don't call your variable `dict` or you will shadow the built-in type.

Comment: @tripleee My csv has the first row Email, Password and afterwards a few emails and passwords. When I run it the print returns {}, so an empty dict.

Comment: please share a sample of your input file

Comment: It might help to open the input file like this `open('email_list_test.csv', 'r', newline='')` as a footnote in the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3) suggests.

Comment: I don't think this is going to help. It can help in write mode but read mode works all the time without newline parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
credentials = {}

with open('email_list_test.csv', 'r') as f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';') # replace the delimiter character with the one you're using.

    for row in reader:
        credentials.update(row)
```

Comment: This is kind of working, athough I am somehow getting my headers as the key for the dictionary.

{'Email;Password': 'meyer.tim1993@gmail.com;Mybuyin2018!'}

Comment: I think my issue somehow comes from the csv file. That its not detecting the headers correctly

Comment: What are you using as separator in your CSV?

Comment: This csv is created on a german pc, which uses ; not , I think. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Easy try this:

```
my_dict = {}

with open('email_list_test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        my_dict[row['Email']] = row['Password']
print(my_dict )
```

Comment: of course if a email is in your csv twice with two different passwords only the last password will be saved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I was hoping it would be this easy. I tried implementing, but my dict stays empty if I do the code as shown above

Comment: not shure I just tested it and its working for me sorry.

Comment: I think the issue might be with the csv file that it is not detecting the headers properly. I dont know why though as they show up properly in the first row when opening the csv in excel